# Вызов функции

Tags: jquery, функции, javascript

Сама функция:

```
function _box(width, params) {
 var tmpl = '<button id="send">Отправить</button>';
 $('body').append(tmpl);
 $('#send').click(function() {
  params._send();
 });
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
_box(400, {_send: function() {
 alert(1);
}})
```

Но происходит такая фигня, что при вызове _box сразу и появляется alert(1), хотя в коде прописано, что должно вызываться по клику.

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас каких-либо других alert'ов нету случаем? потому что : [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/4uWCa/)